# Setup tools install command differences

Tags: python, setuptools

What are the differences between the below commands

```
python setup.py install develop
```

Doesn't work for me error No such file or directory: 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/test-easy-install-37886.pth'

```
python setup.py develop
```

Works for me appears to make an .egg link file

```
python setup.py install
```

Works for me appears to make a .egg file which in .zip file format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Develop is a setuptools / distribute feature that allows you to add a project 
>   to your Python environment without installing it - so you can continue 
>   its "development"
>
> In other words, when you call "python setup.py develop", setuptools will 
>   compile the metadata and hook your project into Python's site-package,
>   but the packages and modules that will be used are the one in the 
>   directory where you've run that command.
>
> This is useful to continue working on your code and testing it without 
>   having to run "python setup.py install" on every run

With develop, Python 'pseudo-installs' a package by running the setup.py script instead of install. The difference is a modification of the environment (it doesn't with develop), so a package can be imported from it's current location instead of a site-package directory. The advantage of this is you can develop packages that are being used by other packages, and you can modify source code in place with develop.

As far as "setup.py install develop", I've never seen anyone use that before, sorry.

[source](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)

[source](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode)

[source](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-September/631175.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
python setup.py install develop
```

Is a wrong command.

When you use `develop` you use the current code when you run your application.

When you use `install` and then modify you code, your modifications will not be taken in account while running your app. until you rerun `install` or `develop`.